# What is the meaning of "What light through yonder window breaks?"?

Tags: meaning

I came across a question in *Romeo and Juliet*:

> But soft! *What light through yonder window breaks?* It is the East, and Juliet is the sun! Arise, fair sun, and kill the envious moon, Who is already sick and pale with grief.

I could analyze it as: What light (through yonder window) breaks?
However, I still couldn’t comprehend the meaning.

Comment: What light breaks through that window? What light suddenly appears through that window?

Comment: For the postponed verb/adverbial phrase before-the-verb, compare: *Something wicked this way **comes***

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo does it mean come this way?

Comment: Yes, the phrase adds information about the direction of the action "comes". Something wicked is coming *towards* us/me.

Comment: Shakespeare is comparing Juliet to the sunrise, a thing of great beauty and wonder.

Answer (score 3):

What light through yonder window breaks?

Translation: what light shines in or comes in through that window?

However, the Bard has chosen to say **breaks** as in: **the sun breaks through clouds**,  where the window would then be like a cloud, and thus obscures, like a cloud, what lies beyond it, that is, the blue sky. Or expressed more clearly: a window is like a cloud. A cloud hides they sky and a window can hide a view unless you are right next to it looking out.

A common image in English is: The sun broke through the clouds after the rain.

Comment: So the prepositional phrase “through yonder window” should follow “breaks”, right?

Comment: Not exactly......There is post-positioning of the phrase from what is usual: the light breaks through yonder window. It is a poetic ordering of the  prepositional phrase (before the verb), and very common in poetry (still) and Shakespeare .

Answer (score 2):

An important context for

> But soft! What light through yonder window breaks?

is that Romeo is below outside, looking up to Juliet's window, whereas usually ***sunlight would enter*** a window, Romeo is saying the ***(sun)light is exiting*** the window.

He is comparing her appearance to the rising sun: **Day Break**, **Break of Dawn**